# Initializing OpenGL with depth buffer and depth testing

Tags: c#, opengl

I would like to initialize OpenGL with a depth-buffer in a platform independent manner without using GLUT.

How to remove hidden-surface in OpenGL scene using c# wrapper.
I'm not using GLUT so I can't use glutInitDisplayMode.
any idea?

---

For more details:

I found these steps about Hidden-Surface removal:

1. Request for z-buffer via glutInitDisplayMode:

   ```
   // GLUT_DEPTH to request for depth-buffer
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
   ```
2. Enable z-buffer for depth testing:

   ```
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   ```
3. Clear the z-buffer when we clear the color buffer:

   ```
   // Clear color and depth buffers
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   ```

as I know, glutInitDisplayMode is one of GLUT functions.
can i eliminate this call without bad effect.
if not, what is the alternative pure opengl calls that do the trick.

I'm using a c# wrapper written by [(Colin P. Fahey)](http://www.colinfahey.com/opengl/csharp.htm)

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without you telling us what you're using to initialize OpenGL. Are you calling WGL directly, or using some library, or what?

Comment: I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 2):

*GLUT is not OpenGL!*

Whatever GLUT does, your C# wrapper probably offers it as well, and probably better. What you need are a **depth buffer** and enabling **depth testing**.

---

#### Update in reflection of question edit

The exact steps to be taken to get a depth buffer depend entirely on the wrapper you use. So it's essential to tell us, which wrapper it is.

Comment: i know that "GLUT is not OpenGL", but i found this steps in many opengl web sites:

1- Request for z-buffer via glutInitDisplayMode:

   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
   // GLUT_DEPTH to request for depth-buffer

2- Enable z-buffer for depth testing:

   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

3- Clear the z-buffer when we clear the color buffer:

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

so, i'm asking about how to replace the first step with pure opengl calls.

Comment: @rami: you should add that to your question with good formatting

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a platform agnostic rendering API. Creating an OpenGL context for a windowing system is the job of the windowing system interface (for example, [WGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGL_%28software%29)).

Depending on what C# bindings you're using, you may have direct wgl or glx calls or a GLUT-like platform independent set of windowing calls (like this in the case of [OpenTK](http://opentk.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opentk/trunk/Source/OpenTK/Platform/INativeGLWindow.cs?revision=3125&view=markup)). I can provide more information if you let us know what bindings you use.

Comment: I'm using a c# wrapper written by (Colin P. Fahey) http://www.colinfahey.com/opengl/csharp.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an interface that isn't so... oddball? I'm all for finding different and interesting tools written by random people, but that documentation is pretty horrible.

I looked through it, and it appears that its InitializeOpenGL command doesn't allow you to set *any* parameters for GL initialization. At all. Which means that you're pretty much at the mercy of the control.

Now, it *probably* will give you a depth buffer by default (and quite frankly if it doesn't, then it's completely worthless and you should abandon it immediately if not sooner). But since there is no way to tell it what you want to do with your buffers, there's nothing you can do to *ensure* it.

Personally, I would advise you to ditch this tool and use something more mainstream like [OpenTK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opentk/). Granted, the stable release of OpenTK is pretty ancient, but it's still better than what you're using now.

Comment: oddball!!!?
It's used by Esri ArcGis Globe demo examples!
I don't think Esri chooses a bad library.

In any case, thank you for your advice, I'll test it.

Comment: @rami: I've never heard of Esri or ArcGis before. However, as I said, you're at the mercy of your tool. It doesn't allow you to ask for a depth buffer. Therefore, whether you get a depth buffer depends entirely on whether your tool will give you one. So if you're not getting one, then that's not something you can solve without modifying the tool.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I'm working on OpenTK now as you adviced,
Surely it's more complete than the library i mentioned.
thanks Nicol.

( Just for information :) : Esri is (almost) a leader of Geographic Information System development (GIS) and ArcGIS is thier complete system for designing and managing solutions through the application of geographic knowledge )

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sequence of OpenGL calls to activate the depth buffer and to enable depth testing (in C):

```
GLuint depth_buffer;
// Generate an id for the buffer object
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth_buffer);
// Bind the object to the OpenGL context
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_buffer);
// Allocate storage
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);
// Attach the depth buffer to the frame buffer
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_buffer);
// Enable OpenGL depth test
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```