# Glut glutSolidSphere works incorrectly

Tags: c#, opengl, glut

I've got a problem when drawing a simple sphere, using GLUT. When i'm drawing a sphere the application draws just a black form (my backgroung color is white), and when i'm trying to draw a wire cube i get just a black dot. 
Here's my code

```
private void init()
{
    Glut.glutInit();
    Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_SINGLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE);

    Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

    Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT.Width, AnT.Height);

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Glu.gluPerspective(45, (float)AnT.Width / (float)AnT.Height, 0.1, 200);

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);
}


private void draw()
{
    Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();

    //Glut.glutWireCube(100);
    Glut.glutSolidSphere(1, 16, 16);

    Gl.glPopMatrix();
    Gl.glFlush();
    AnT.Invalidate();
}
```

My init function is called on loading the form and my draw function - on painting it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Checkout this stackoverflow posting and see if the comments / answers can help solve your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292733/initializing-opengl-with-depth-buffer-and-depth-testing

Comment: @DJKRAZE, unfortunately I don't get the idea of that topic, because i've just started using openGL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Glut.GLUT_SINGLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE
```

`GLUT_SINGLE` and `GLUT_DOUBLE` are mutually exclusive.  Pick one.

```
Gl.glPopMatrix();
```

You're missing a corresponding `glPushMatrix()`, though for this particular use-case you don't need either.

```
Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

`glClearColor()` takes `float`s between 0.0 and 1.0.

---

Try this sequence instead:

```
private void init()
{
    Glut.glutInit();
    Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_SINGLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB);
    Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT.Width, AnT.Height);
}

private void draw()
{
    Gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Glu.gluPerspective(45, (float)AnT.Width / (float)AnT.Height, 0.1, 200);

    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);

    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CULL_FACE);
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);

    Glut.glutSolidSphere(1, 16, 16);

    // Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
    // Glut.glutWireCube(1);

    Gl.glFinish();
    AnT.Invalidate();
}
```